# how to pass variable from one page to another in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, eloquent, orm

I have been working on a project where the data from the form page will be displayed in the admin page for the admin approval. After submitting data, it will return the user to the same form page with success message. I got the value in the admin page but the system returns the user to the admin page instead of the form page. Here is my code on the controller.

```
class RehomeController extends Controller
{
    public function rehome(Request $show){

            $breed = $show->input('breed');
            $gender = $show->input('gender');
            $age = $show->input('age');
            $color = $show ->color;
            $height = $show ->height;
            $description = $show ->description;
            $health = $show ->health;
            return view('admin.posts')->with('breed',$breed);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are shown your admin page in your return statement. If you wish yo redirect back the user to the original form, just use `return back()->withInput();`in that case you'll have all user data available again through session variables.

Comment: return back('posts')->withInput($breed);   like this??

Comment: No, just `return back()->withInput();` the back function knows which page is the previous one, so no need to specify.